# Blazor blazor.server.js error on initial load

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-jsinterop, blazor-jsruntime

I am getting strange error in the browser console seemingly caused by some JS associated with default JS files that Blazor framework ships. I can;t seem to be able to figure out what this might be related to. All application components seem to be doing OK. Does anyone have any bright ideas that could point me in the right direction of investigating this? the framework unfortunately does not provide much of a comprehensive description of the potential cause of this. thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do you use SVG in your application? Does it have a `<path>` element with those values? Fix it - it is telling you the path is not correct - probably where you have `3.15a1.2`

Comment: @MisterMagoo thanks mate! i would have never intuitively link this to an svg issue. life-saver.